# Teste correto para model (RSpec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rspec

Criei um teste para validar meu modelo e quero saber se ele esta correto.

```ruby
describe Article do
  it "object article create is valid?" do
        article = Article.create
        article.title = "Title for Test"
        article.description = ""
        article.body = "Body for Test"
        article.position_image_highlighted = ""

        expect(article.valid?).to be
    end
end
```

A validação retorna sem falhas, porém não sei se este código possui a melhor prática para o devido teste.

Comment: Este link tem um conteúdo fantástico: http://betterspecs.org/br/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), a baixo segue um exemplo bem simples. Aproveite para dar uma olhada na nova forma de escrever expects no RSpec.

```ruby
describe Article do
  it "expect valid article" do
    article = FactoryGirl.create(:article)    
    expect(article).to be_valid          
  end
end
```

Factory:

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    title "Title for Test"
    description ""
    body "Body for Test"
    position_image_highlighted = ""
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
describe Article do
  it "object article create is valid?" do
    article = Article.new({ # 1
      title: "Title for Test", # 2
      description: "",
      body: "Body for Test",
      position_image_highlighted: ""
    })

    expect(article).to be_valid # 3
  end
end
```

Três alterações principais:

1. A vantagem de usar o `new` ao invés do `create` é que o objeto não será persistido no banco e seu teste ficará mais rápido.
2. Você pode passar um `Hash` para o model e não precisar ficar atribuindo cada campo.
3. o *Matcher* `be_valid` já chama o método `valid?` e verifica se ele retorna `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Use o FactoryGirl como disse o Elvis, porém é recomendado o uso do `let` para deixar o escopo do teste mais limpo, além de algumas outras vantagens citadas no [BetterSpecs](http://betterspecs.org/br/#let).

Minha sugestão é:

FactoryGirl

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    title 'Title for Test'
    description ''
    body 'Body for Test'
    position_image_highlighted = ''
  end
end
```

Spec:

```rb
describe Article do
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.build(:article) }

  it 'is a valid article' do
    expect(article).to be_valid          
  end
end
```

E para testar um artigo inválido seria mais simples e sem duplicações por conta do FactoryGirl. O exemplo mais completo a seguir:

```rb
describe Article do
  context 'with required fields' do
    let(:article) { FactoryGirl.build(:article) }

    it 'is a valid article' do
      expect(article).to be_valid          
    end
  end

  context 'with no title' do
    let(:article) { FactoryGirl.build(:article, title: '') }

    it 'is an invalid article' do
      expect(article).to_not be_valid          
    end
  end
end
```